# How popular are the different styles of Aikido?

Tags: aikido

I've been reading about the [different styles of Aikido on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aikido_styles) and I was wondering how popular each style is? I know that in my country the vast majority of schools teach Aikikai style (I estimate about 75% of all schools), but how is this elsewhere?

I'm aware that popularity may be hard to quantify, but perhaps there is data somewhere on the number of registered practioners or registered dojo's?

Comment: How would that information be useful?  And wouldn't the answer be intrinsically localized? (not arguing, just exploring)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I'm interested in how popular Aikido styles are world-wide, so IMHO the answer isn't localized. It now seems likely that these numbers do not exist, so I'll settle for rough estimates or data on specific countries/regions, but I agree that will make the question (more) localised.  My rationale for asking is that it can be a (minor) factor in choosing a particular style.

Answer (score 3):

In the UK, you could look at the [British Aikido Board](http://www.bab.org.uk/) which covers most if not all the organisation that are teaching Aikido in the UK.  This will not give you a clear idea of participants (some organisation are one dojo with 3 people in it) but it should give you an overview.

Note that the [British Aikido Board](http://www.bab.org.uk/) has had a mass exodus of clubs for various reasons that are utterly irrelevant here.  All in the spirit of Aikido's harmony⸮  So, it might no longer reflect all the clubs in the UK.

[Aikiweb](http://www.aikiweb.com/) used to run some polls as to what its members where doing like [this one](http://www.aikiweb.com/polls/results.html?poll_id=3) but I am not sure this is still accurate as it is more than ten years old.

Comment: Thanks for the links! British Aikido board does give a some insight into popularity. I also found a similar website for [Aikido dojo's in the Netherlands](http://www.aikidonederland.nl/dojos.html) myself. Still would like to see some numbers on popularity worldwide though.

Comment: I am not sure that this data exists.  You could ask the different hombu dojo in Japan as they should have a list of all the yudansha that are registered with them but that gives you only shodan or above that have registered...

Comment: And it will neglect all the "independent", unaffiliated, etc.  I begin to wonder if those outnumber the "affiliated" schools.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: A fair few "independent" dojo are still part of the BAB as they can get cheap insurance via them.

Comment: The reason for the exodus, while irrelevant to the answer, would be very interesting to know.

Comment: @Hashim The reason is simple, tedious, and pathetic: ego.

Comment: @Sardathrion But what actually happened? It sounds like it would be very interesting history.

Comment: @Hashim A google search will provide you with all the drama. *Really, it is not worth your time.*